# Задержка между повторами анимации в SVG

Tags: xml, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Учился делать SVG анимацию, всё получилось. Я хотел зацикленную анимацию с задержкой в несколько секунд между повторениями. Зацикленность я получил, но не задержку.

```css
 .logoPath {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 35;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    .logoColor {
        stroke: #5db3e6;
     }
```

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 2739.1 3607.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2739.1 3607.7;" xml:space="preserve">
 <path class="logoPath logoColor" d="M1389.9,899.5c0,0,18,150,66,174s198-36,198-36S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z">
  <animate
    attributeName="d"
    begin="0.5s"
    dur="0.5s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="remove"
    values="M1389.9,899.5c0,0,18,150,66,174s198-36,198-36S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z;
     M1389.9,899.5c0,0,81.5,26.4,129.5,50.4s134.5,87.6,134.5,87.6S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z;
     M1389.9,899.5c0,0,81.5,26.4,129.5,50.4s134.5,87.6,134.5,87.6S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z;
     M1389.9,899.5c0,0,18,150,66,174s198-36,198-36S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z"
  />
 </path>
 <path class="logoPath logoColor" d="M680.7,2597.5c-72,420,195,594,195,594c-31.5-182.1,147-496,147-496c4,488,400,552,400,552
 c-204-196-116-690-116-690c272,304,248,952,248,952c336-644,74-1153,74-1153c236,188,252,568,252,568
 c248.7-313.5,152.1-630.7,63.4-803.5c-35.7-69.6-91.8-126.6-160.9-163.4c-282.5-150.2-309.6-366.7-309.6-366.7
 c196.9,132.3,616.7,193.8,771.5,212.6c81.6,9.9,164.4-7.9,233.8-51.8c170.8-108.1,186.6-321,186.6-321c-180-150-725.3-409-725.3-409
 S1758.7,481,1204.7,421.5c0,0-19.5-204.9,26-390c-11.5,4.4-274.6,75.2-378.9,341.9c-21.8,55.7-62,109.8-120.3,122.8
 C498.3,548.5,76.4,841.6,53.7,1257.5c0,0,162-134,214-146c0,0-354,617-214,906c0,0,63.9-163,194-240c0,0-230,588-54,932
 c0,0,78-224,166-276c0,0-105,454,247,1038C606.7,3471.5,498.7,3011.5,680.7,2597.5z"/>
 <path class="logoPath logoColor" d="M2505,1321c0,0,72.9,259.2,114.3,269.1"/>
 <path class="logoPath logoColor" d="M1204.7,213.5c0,0,36-128,158-174c0,0-50,339,47,430"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я хотел зацикленную анимацию с задержкой в несколько секунд между
>   повторениями.

Паузу между анимациями моргания века можно получить с помощью добавления второй анимации - паузы, которая ничего не делает (ждет: `dur="2s"`) и после завершения длительности этой анимации паузы, запускается вновь первая анимация моргания века.

**Пауза**

```
<animate id="pause"
                attributeName="d"
                begin=an1.end"
                dur="2s"
                repeatCount="1"
                fill="freeze"
                values=""
        />
```

где `begin=an1.end"` - обозначает запуск анимации паузы, после окончания первой анимации `id="an1"`

**Зацикливание анимации моргания**

`begin="svg1.click;pause.end"`

Это условие говорит нам, что первый запуск анимации начнется после клика по холсту SVG, а повторный запуск этой же анимации начинается после окончания анимации паузы.

```css
.logoPath {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 35;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    .logoColor {
        stroke: #5db3e6;
     }
```

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"?>
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="30%" height="30%"
  viewBox="0 0 2739.1 3607.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2739.1 3607.7;" xml:space="preserve">
 <path fill="gold" class="logoPath logoColor" d="M1389.9,899.5c0,0,18,150,66,174s198-36,198-36S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z">
  <animate
    attributeName="d" id="an1"
    begin="svg1.click;pause.end"
    dur="0.5s"
    repeatCount="3"
    fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive"
    values="M1389.9,899.5c0,0,18,150,66,174s198-36,198-36S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z;
     M1389.9,899.5c0,0,81.5,26.4,129.5,50.4s134.5,87.6,134.5,87.6S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z;
     M1389.9,899.5c0,0,81.5,26.4,129.5,50.4s134.5,87.6,134.5,87.6S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z;
     M1389.9,899.5c0,0,18,150,66,174s198-36,198-36S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z"
  />  
  <animate
    <animate id="pause"
    attributeName="d"
    begin="an1.end"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive"
    values="M1389.9,899.5c0,0,18,150,66,174s198-36,198-36S1473.9,881.5,1389.9,899.5z"
  />
  
 </path>
 <path class="logoPath logoColor" d="M680.7,2597.5c-72,420,195,594,195,594c-31.5-182.1,147-496,147-496c4,488,400,552,400,552
 c-204-196-116-690-116-690c272,304,248,952,248,952c336-644,74-1153,74-1153c236,188,252,568,252,568
 c248.7-313.5,152.1-630.7,63.4-803.5c-35.7-69.6-91.8-126.6-160.9-163.4c-282.5-150.2-309.6-366.7-309.6-366.7
 c196.9,132.3,616.7,193.8,771.5,212.6c81.6,9.9,164.4-7.9,233.8-51.8c170.8-108.1,186.6-321,186.6-321c-180-150-725.3-409-725.3-409
 S1758.7,481,1204.7,421.5c0,0-19.5-204.9,26-390c-11.5,4.4-274.6,75.2-378.9,341.9c-21.8,55.7-62,109.8-120.3,122.8
 C498.3,548.5,76.4,841.6,53.7,1257.5c0,0,162-134,214-146c0,0-354,617-214,906c0,0,63.9-163,194-240c0,0-230,588-54,932
 c0,0,78-224,166-276c0,0-105,454,247,1038C606.7,3471.5,498.7,3011.5,680.7,2597.5z"/>
 <path class="logoPath logoColor" d="M2505,1321c0,0,72.9,259.2,114.3,269.1"/>
 <path class="logoPath logoColor" d="M1204.7,213.5c0,0,36-128,158-174c0,0-50,339,47,430"/>
</svg>
```